# Trying to clone Azure pipeline but getting "references service connection ... not found" error

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, clone

I want to clone an Azure pipeline that builds from a Git repo.  Following the instructions here -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/clone-import-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#clone-a-pipeline , I clicked "Clone" when clicking "Edit" on the pipeline ...

[image]

and then on the following screen changed the branch from where the repository builds and clicked "Save".  After entering my comment and saving, I got this error ...

```
The pipeline is not valid. Job Job_2: Step input connectedServiceNameARM references service connection 2b45...959e8d3d which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz. Job Job_1: Step input connectedServiceNameARM references service connection 2b45...959e8d3d which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.
```

I "think" the error message is referring to the "Agent Job" part of the pipeline, which looks like the below

[image]

I'm clueless about what the error message is referring to and am curious about if there is a way to clone my pipeline.

**Edit:** In response to the answer given, turns out I don't have any service connections defined in my project at all.  When I click on the "service connections" link in the project settings, all I see is this ...

[image]

Comment: It sounds like it could be a service connection that needs to be updated.

Comment: If that were true, wouldn't that mean that the pipeline from which this is cloned would fail to run?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem on my side. You need to check whether the service connections used in your pipeline exist in the **Service connections** of **Project Settings**. If the service connections have been deleted, you will get this error when you clone the pipeline.

[image]

Comment: Where do you access Project Settings?  When I click on the project in question, I don't see that as an option along the left nav options -- https://imgur.com/a/W2HZnUq

Comment: Scratch that -- I found it (buried at the lower left).  However, I don't have any service connections defined in my project (included screen shot as an edit to my question).

Comment: Are service connections used in the pipeline you want to clone? If there are, please remove them or use new ones instead. If the service connections you use do not exist, you will get the error.

Comment: You need to check which tasks use non-existent service connections in pipleine definition.

Comment: Hi @Hugh Lin, Per my screen shot, in the edit to my question, I was trying to show I have no service connections.  Also, if I did have non-functioning service connections, that would mean I'd be unable to make changes to the source pipeline (save would fail for the source pipeline too), right?  But I'm able to save the source pipeline just fine.

Comment: Turned out the "bug" was that I didn't have proper permissions to clone the pipeline.

Comment: @Dave Glad to hear this issue is solved. You can convert this into an answer and accept it . So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation to comment here, but your error message makes it look like you are trying to deploy to Azure through your pipeline.  This is probably not necessary for a simple build job. From the menu where you clone the pipeline try export YAML.
[Export to YML menu pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XolDr.png)
That will show the details of Job_2 and might give you the hint that you need to find the step in the UI.

If there isn't a corresponding step in the UI where you can clear out the service connection then you may be stuck creating a new pipeline and manually copying the steps you do have access to in the UI. You could also create a new pipeline based on the YAML file you just exported minus the problematic job.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error message because I used the following wrong endpoint:

```
SonarQube – zb6Mt – my-project
```

When I changed it for this endpoint, it fixed the error

```
SonarQube -- zb6Mt -- my-project
```